# "No way!" and "As if!" are the same?

Tags: word-difference, conversation

Are you seeing anyone?
1: No way!   2: As if!

Did you read my diaries?
3: No way!   4: As if!

Do all of the answers sounds natural?
If not, which ones are natural and/or weird 
and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: (There is) No way (I would do that)! As if (I would ever do that)!

Answer (score 2):

In your examples

> **No way!**

is often used as a strong denial of *something*, and is used as shorthand for **no way, jose**, a kind of rhyming slang.

> **As if!**

is shorthand for

> **As if** *I would do something like that*

however context would have to built around habitual actions of the accused to support the **as if!**

A related phrase is

> **Why would I?**
>   *why would I do something like that*

which is an implicit denial of the accusation and also throws back a question to the accuser.

Answer (score 1):

All of those answers make sense, and you can even use both right after one another for any of these questions.

"No way! As if!" Makes perfect sense.

'No way' means that you are implying that there is no way that you could have done something.

'As if!' Is a defensive remark that pretty much means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Do all of the answers sound natural? **Yes**.

No way! -> provides strong objection to what was said.

As if! -> may provide the message 'stop assuming'.